# Byte Array to Byte conversion error

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, byte, arrays, implicit-conversion

I am trying to flip the bits of an unsigned 32-bit integer and output the resultant integer. The following is my code.

```
int numberOfTries = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTries; i++)
        {
            uint input = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            byte[] bInput = BitConverter.GetBytes(input);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(bInput);
            byte[] result = bInput;

            BitArray b = new BitArray(new byte[] { result });
            b.Not();
            uint res = 0;
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 != 32; i2++)
            {
                if (b[i2])
                {
                    res |= (uint)(1 << i2);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
```

However, the compiler complains that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte' " on the line where I declare BitArray b. I have declared it as a byte[] and have no idea why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is already a `byte[]`, so do this instead:

```
BitArray b = new BitArray(result);
```

The part that's actually causing the problem is this:

```
new byte[] { result }
```

The reason for this is because the array initializer needs to take expressions that are compatible with the element type of the array (here, `byte`). From [12.6 Array Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx):

> For a single-dimensional array, the array initializer must consist of a sequence of expressions that are assignment compatible with the element type of the array.